# Trying to load data into a table using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to load data into a table using PostgresSQL10.4 and pgAdmin4. My query is below. When I try to use \copy I get the below error.

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (TimeDate date, Yield float(3))
SELECT * FROM mydata
\copy mydata FROM 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\Stock Prices.csv' WITH CSV;
```

The above results in the following error:

**ERROR:**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \copy mydata FROM 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\Stock Pri...
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/postgresql-import-csv-file-causes-syntax-error

Comment: I read the answer and it seems like I cannot perform this, but the only reason I am doing this, is to avoid the permission that needs to be granted when running `COPY FROM...`. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on that particular table & select option to 'Import/Export data" and provide file you want to load into that table.

Answer (score 1):

`\copy` is a tool particular to the psql program.  Other programs have their own variants to accomplish the same thing.  In the case of PgAdmin4, you right-click on the table in the tree viewer and select "Import/Export..."